# How to create table which shows how many skills in common for persons?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I have a table which looks like below:

```
Person Skill_1 Skill_2 Skill_3 Skill_4   
A        X       X       X
B                X       
C                X
D        X       X             X
E                              X
```

I want to create a table (or modify this table) which shows for each person a sorted list of people according to how many skills they have in common. For example, for person A, a drop down list showing that person D has 2 skills in common, person B has one skill in common, person C also has one skill in common (whereas person E has no skills in common so shouldn't be on the list).

To be more specific, I have a list of people and and want to identify for each person who are the other people with common skills. Hence, for each person a list (sorted descending by number of skills in common) of other persons.

How do I do this in Microsoft excel?

Comment: I have edited the question, not sure why it is closed. It says I am asking on more than one problem but I don't think that is the case

Answer (score 1):

If i understood it right, You can do this in a second sheet. You can use [Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-macro-cells-change) to Watch, if someone changed the Cell you added a Dropdown list. You have to write an IF-Statement in the Change Event. I will test it by my self too, and Post my Solution. Interesting Question!